# Python beautifulsoup loop till date changes

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have been stuck for 3 days now and i need help. Maybe its very simple but i cant figure it out. I recently started with soup.

I want to get this result from hltv.org/matches

### 2020-05-22 Friday

team1 vs team2
and so on.

### 2020-05-23 Saturday

team1 vs team2
and so on.

What my code does now is that it gets the date but it prints all matches under every date. It doensnt sort out by date.(not strange since i havent figure that out yet.)
I dont know how to like tell it to; if date changes then print correct date and correct teams under each date.

```
# get upcoming matches
result_1 = soup.find_all("div", class_="upcoming-match standard-box")

# get date
result_2 = soup.find_all(class_="match-day")

# set date
date = ""

# loop through result_2 and find date 
for x in result_2:
    date = x.find("span", class_="standard-headline").text
    print (date)

    # loop through result_1 and find every match.
    for x2 in result_1:

        # problem!!!
        # if date changes then break this loop and print correct date and re-enter this loop. 

        # get team1 and team2 and print.
        team1 = x2.find("div", class_="team").text
        team2 = x2.find("div", class_="team").findNext("div").text
        print ("{} vs {}".format(team1,team2))
```

Hope someone can help. Thanks!

Comment: What does the data look like in result_1 & result_2?  Can you see the date in result_2 alongside each match? If so you could do this with one loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reorganized your code a bit. The way to read it is - find all match days, then, for each match day find all games happening that day.

Note you have an exceptional case where there are no explicit matches. See for example date 2020-06-04, check the HTML structure for such dates, and you will understand why the use of `try - except` block.

```
match_days = soup.find_all(class_="match-day")

for day in match_days:
    matches = day.find_all("div", class_="upcoming-match standard-box")
    date = day.find("span", class_="standard-headline").text
    print(date)
    for match in matches:
        try:
            team1 = match.find("div", class_="team").text
            team2 = match.find("div", class_="team").findNext("div").text
            print("{} vs {}".format(team1,team2))
        except AttributeError:
            placeholder=match.find("td",class_="placeholder-text-cell").text
            print(placeholder)
```

Comment: That worked perfekt 0buz. Thank you very much! i have been thinking of this like crazy last days..Iam going to study this code and see how you did and learn from that code..

Comment: No worries. Have a hack at it and if you still have questions just ask.